# handling table prefix without any database config file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

We know codeigniter allows us to use prefix for tables and we need to define prefix in database.php file. However, I want to do something different. I have a script and any user who will have that and install it, the installation page will ask typical configuration settings including if user want to use any prefix for tables before it could install the database. I want to store that prefix in a setting table and want to get the prefix from database ('setting' table) rather than defining the prefix in database.php. Wordpress does the same in installation time. Any we can even change prefix in Wordpress later anytime.

This way my users (who are buyer of my script) who might not be programmers, they should be able to easily change their tables prefix via admin side anytime.

I do not want them to change prefix from config files.

If I will store the prefix in any table then prefix will be applied to that table as well (in above case settings table will become prefix_settings) and then to fetch (via query) the updated prefix which is stored in setting table I need to know what is prefix because the setting table is also having that new prefix :)

Note: This is not bound to Codeigniter only. This is general question for any website which has database. I am just working on a project in CI so giving example how CI handles prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can set db prefix manually in ci. Give it a try

1. Create a table where all users setting data will be available. Such as

   ```
   //user_setting table columns
   id, user_id, db_prefix, site_url, .......,
   ```
2. Now get all setting data from user setting table where your user `db_prefix` is also available.

sample query : `"SELECT * FROM user_setting WHERE user_id = 105"`

3. Now use the setting data.

   ```
   // For example, say it is $setting['db_prefix']

   if(!empty($setting['db_prefix'])){
     $this->db->set_dbprefix('newprefix');
     $db_prefix = $this->db->dbprefix('tablename');
   }else{
      $db_prefix = '';
   }
   ```

Now concat `$db_prefix` with your table name. Hope it will work.

Comment: Actually I want a solution where the prefix comes itself from database. In CI scenario which I already know and requires to add prefix in database file or we can set through code. But I want to give this option to end user from admin panel. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: That's why i mentioned you to get db_prefix from admin, i used $setting['db_prefix']) as example. However i updated my answer with detail explanation. Hope it may help you

Comment: So in above scenario, the user settings table will not have any prefix right? And if we have to change prefix we will replace all other table's prefix but setting table will have no prefix since we will need that table to get the prefix it self. That solution is good but I wanted something like Wordpress which I am not sure how they are doing. They have all table with same prefix. Even the one which holds prefix value stored.

Answer (score 0):

In your **config/database.php** there would be an parameter called

```
'dbprefix' => 'userDefinedPrefix',
```

Set you prefix in it and now you can use it in your model

```
 $this->anyName = $this->db->dbprefix('table_name');
```

Comment: I think I am not able to put the question in clear way :(